# Aggregate data grouped by date but from different date fields

Tags: mongodb, statistics, aggregation

I'm trying to get a query where the output is grouped by date, but the next fields will be based on different date fields.

So, for the date 2018-11 (year-month), how many registers were, how many activations were, how many customers and how many cancels. But each register/activation/customer/cancel, has to be counted in the month when it happened.

My data is stored  as follow:

```
{
        "track" : {
                "hasBeenCustomer" : true,
                "hasActivated" : true,
                "hasActivatedAt" : ISODate("2018-08-21T14:32:53.929Z"),
                "hasBeenCustomerAt" : ISODate("2019-02-26T07:21:06Z"),
                "hasRegisteredAt" : ISODate("2018-08-09T10:17:38.329Z"),
                "hasCanceled" : true,
                "hasCanceledAt" : ISODate("2019-04-29T13:56:04Z")
        }
}
{
        "track" : {
                "hasBeenCustomer" : true,
                "hasActivated" : true,
                "hasActivatedAt" : ISODate("2018-08-26T15:04:58.854Z"),
                "hasBeenCustomerAt" : ISODate("2018-11-24T10:37:14Z"),
                "hasRegisteredAt" : ISODate("2018-08-25T11:12:36.309Z"),
                "hasCanceled" : true,
                "hasCanceledAt" : ISODate("2019-05-30T18:11:04Z")
        }
}
{
        "track" : {
                "hasBeenCustomer" : true,
                "hasActivated" : true,
                "hasActivatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-24T23:21:55.733Z"),
                "hasBeenCustomerAt" : ISODate("2019-03-12T10:26:01Z"),
                "hasRegisteredAt" : ISODate("2018-09-22T17:56:57.256Z"),
                "hasCanceled" : true,
                "hasCanceledAt" : ISODate("2019-04-12T10:22:03Z")
        }
}
{
        "track" : {
                "hasBeenCustomer" : true,
                "hasActivated" : true,
                "hasActivatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-18T15:08:15.351Z"),
                "hasBeenCustomerAt" : ISODate("2018-12-22T21:37:01Z"),
                "hasRegisteredAt" : ISODate("2018-10-16T03:54:16.056Z"),
                "hasCanceled" : true,
                "hasCanceledAt" : ISODate("2019-01-22T21:39:03Z")
        }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
db.user.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            $match: 
                { 
                    projectId : "00001"
                } 
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "createDate": { 
                    "$dateToString": { 
                        "format": "%Y-%m", 
                        "date": "$track.hasRegisteredAt" 
                    } 
                },
                activationAt: { 
                    "$dateToString": { 
                        "format": "%Y-%m", 
                        "date": "$track.hasActivatedAt" 
                    } 
                },
                customerAt: { 
                    "$dateToString": { 
                        "format": "%Y-%m", 
                        "date": "$track.hasBeenCustomerAt" 
                    } 
                },
                cancelAt: { 
                    "$dateToString": { 
                        "format": "%Y-%m", 
                        "date": "$track.hasCanceledAt" 
                    } 
                },
                activations: { 
          "$sum": { 
              "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$track.hasActivated", true ] },
                  1,
                  0
              ]
          }
        },              
                customers: { 
          "$sum": { 
              "$cond": [
                  { "$eq": [ "$track.hasBeenCustomer", true ] },
                  1,
                  0
              ]
          }
        },
                cancels: { 
          "$sum": { 
              "$cond": [{ 
                                "$and": [ 
                                    { "$eq": [ "$status", 3 ] },
                                    { "$eq": [ "$track.hasCanceled", true ] }
                                ]},  
                  1,
                  0
              ]
          }
        }
            }
        },      
        {
            $group:
                {
                    _id: "$createDate",
                    users: {$sum: 1},
                    activations: {$sum: "$activations"},
                    activationsM: { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$activationAt", "$createDate" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
            },
                    customers: {$sum: "$customers"},
                    customersM: { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$customerAt", "$createDate" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
            },
                    cancels: {$sum: "$cancels"},
                    cancelsM: { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$cancelAt", "$createDate" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
            },
                }
        },
        {
            $sort: 
                { 
                    _id: 1
                }
        }
    ]
)
```

activationsM, customersM, cancelsM, are supposed to be the counting per month, independently from the _id field, but I have realized that, this query relieves in results matching the _id, and once it matches it, then it check the condintion. I need it to be sum, even if the _id doesn't match the hasActivatedAt, hasBeenCustomerAt, hasCanceledAt fields.

Hope I have explained it properly.

The desired output would be:

```
{ "_id" : "2018-06", "users" : 18, "activations" : 5, "activationsM" : 2, "customers" : 4, "customersM" : 0, "cancels" : 1, "cancelsM" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "2018-07", "users" : 78, "activations" : 39, "activationsM" : 31, "customers" : 11, "customersM" : 0, "cancels" : 7, "cancelsM" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "2018-08", "users" : 115, "activations" : 49, "activationsM" : 38, "customers" : 18, "customersM" : 0, "cancels" : 8, "cancelsM" : 0 }
```

Being **fiedlM** the total count for the correspondient field date and the _id date field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "TOTAL_ACTIVATION": [
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: "$track.hasActivated",
                        total: { "$sum": 1 }, 
                        "totalActiveCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasActivated", true ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                        "totalNonActiveCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasActivated", false ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },

                    }
                }
            ],
            "TOTAL_CUSTOMERS": [
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: "$track.hasBeenCustomer",
                        total: { "$sum": 1 },
                        "totalCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasBeenCustomer", true ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                        "totalNonCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasBeenCustomer", false ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                    }
                }
            ],
            "TOTAL_CANCELLED": [
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: "$track.hasCanceled",
                        total: { "$sum": 1 },
                        "totalCancelledCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasCanceled", true ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                        "totalNonCancelledCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasCanceled", false ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                    }
                }
            ],
            "MONTHLY_ACTIVATION" : [
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: {
                            year: { $year: "$track.hasActivatedAt" },
                            month: { $month: "$track.hasActivatedAt" }
                        },
                        totalThisMonth: { $sum : 1},
                        "totalActiveCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasActivated", true ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                        "totalNonActiveCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasActivated", false ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                    }   
                }

            ],
            "MONTHLY_CUSTOMER" : [
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: {
                            year: { $year: "$track.hasBeenCustomerAt" },
                            month: { $month: "$track.hasBeenCustomerAt" }
                        },
                        totalThisMonth: { $sum : 1},
                        "totalCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasBeenCustomer", true ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                        "totalNonCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasBeenCustomer", false ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                    }   
                }

            ],
            "MONTHLY_CANCELLED" : [
                {
                    $group: { 
                        _id: {
                            year: { $year: "$track.hasCanceledAt" },
                            month: { $month: "$track.hasCanceledAt" }
                        },
                        totalThisMonth: { $sum : 1},
                        "totalCancelledCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasCanceled", true ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                        "totalNonCancelledCustomer": {
                            "$sum": { "$cond": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$track.hasCanceled", false ] },
                                1,
                                0
                            ]}
                        },
                    }   
                }

            ]

        }
    }
])
```

Result of this will be as below:

```
{
    "TOTAL_ACTIVATION" : [
        {
            "_id" : true,
            "total" : 4,
            "totalActiveCustomer" : 4,
            "totalNonActiveCustomer" : 0
        }
    ],
    "TOTAL_CUSTOMERS" : [
        {
            "_id" : true,
            "total" : 4,
            "totalCustomer" : 4,
            "totalNonCustomer" : 0
        }
    ],
    "TOTAL_CANCELLED" : [
        {
            "_id" : true,
            "total" : 4,
            "totalCancelledCustomer" : 4,
            "totalNonCancelledCustomer" : 0
        }
    ],
    "MONTHLY_ACTIVATION" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2018),
                "month" : NumberInt(10)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalActiveCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonActiveCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2018),
                "month" : NumberInt(9)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalActiveCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonActiveCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2018),
                "month" : NumberInt(8)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 2,
            "totalActiveCustomer" : 2,
            "totalNonActiveCustomer" : 0
        }
    ],
    "MONTHLY_CUSTOMER" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2018),
                "month" : NumberInt(12)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2019),
                "month" : NumberInt(3)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2018),
                "month" : NumberInt(11)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2019),
                "month" : NumberInt(2)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonCustomer" : 0
        }
    ],
    "MONTHLY_CANCELLED" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2019),
                "month" : NumberInt(1)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalCancelledCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonCancelledCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2019),
                "month" : NumberInt(5)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 1,
            "totalCancelledCustomer" : 1,
            "totalNonCancelledCustomer" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "year" : NumberInt(2019),
                "month" : NumberInt(4)
            },
            "totalThisMonth" : 2,
            "totalCancelledCustomer" : 2,
            "totalNonCancelledCustomer" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey @Jitendra, thanks for your answer. The output gives all the information that I asked for, but the format is far from what I need. Don't know if it's possible to get just the info I needed in the suggested expected format. Anyway, I'll investigate from here. Thanks again.